# import a gml file to gephi - java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, r, igraph, gephi

I have created a gml file with the `r` package `igraph`.
When I try to import it to Gephi for visualisation I get an error message:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Any clue on how to make it work?

*EDIT*

```
graph_rt <- data.frame(from = data$twitter_handle, to = data$RT)
graph_rt <- graph_rt[complete.cases(graph_rt),]
g <- graph.data.frame(graph_rt, directed=TRUE) 
write.graph(g, "~/graph_gephi.gml", format="gml")
```

Comment: which line is it pointing to?

Comment: Actually the message is a pop-up! It does not give any more information

Comment: What is the R igraph code you used to export the file?  In my experience, the Gephi import process is very finicky about precise extensions

Comment: Quite a simple one: `graph_rt <- data.frame(from = data$twitter_handle, to = data$RT)
graph_rt <- graph_rt[complete.cases(graph_rt),]
g <- graph.data.frame(graph_rt, directed=TRUE) write.graph(g, "~/graph_gephi.gml", format="gml")`

Comment: Did you discover what issue was causing this?